# How do I stop javascript from posting twice when clicking off date field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a user clicks on a date field and enters a date, a post request is sent. But then when the user clicks somewhere off the field, the request sends a second time. How do I correct this? I tried `focusout()` but the problem persists.

```js
$(".cInput").focusout(function(){
    var fieldName = this.name;
    var fieldValue = this.value;
    var cid = $('meta[name="cid"]').attr('content');
    var cnum = $('meta[name="cnum"]').attr('content');

    $.ajax({
        /* the route pointing to the post function */
        url: '/cUpdate',
        type: 'POST',
        /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
        data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, moduleID: $("#moduleID").text(), checkName: fieldName, checkValue: fieldValue, cid: cid, cnum: cnum},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
        success: function (data) { 
            window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, thisURL);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What action is supposed to trigger sending the POST request? You should only have that event handler, not any others.

Comment: Do you have multiple `.cInput` elements? You'll send the AJAX request after leaving each of them. You need to make your event handler more specific so that only editing one field triggers the AJAX.

Comment: Or just use a submit button instead of sending the AJAX request when the user edits a field.

Comment: It should post when the date is entered and not when a user clicks off the field. Yes, the cInput currently refers to multiple date fields on the same page, but there are switch cases to handle which field is being posted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. From your code, I see `focusout` is being used. *The focusout event fires when an element is about to lose focus.* You should consider using a different Event. It is not clear if you ate using `date` input type or something like jQuery UI Datepicker. The latter often has a `select` or `onSelect` callback to use when the User selects a date.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example